# Зачем крупные проекты пишут на directx если есть opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, directx

У directx по сравнению с opengl много минусов:
Огромная сложность directx при написании игры
Множество версий в которых можно запутаться
Отсутствие кроссплатформенности(если вы пишите игру или движок с использованием directx, то можно забыть про все платформы кроме винды)
Не такая большая скорость как у opengl.

Однако где я не посмотрю, почти все хорошие игры написаны на directx, движки пишут на directx, и прочие огромные проекты написаны на directx. А что бы найти что то более менее годное на opengl, нужно ещё постараться. Так в чем секрет directx? Почему именно он?

Comment: `Не такая большая скорость как у opengl` - всё наоборот: реализация opengl более тормозная, и она такая последние 15 лет, никто не верит что она когда-нибудь взлетит.  все молятся на количество FPS

Comment: В том, что на Xbox никакого opengl никогда не будет, например?

Comment: За исключением отсутствия кроссплатформенности, перечисленные минусы вообще ни разу не соответствуют действительности. Вот напирмер "Множество версий в которых можно запутаться" - в DX по сути актуальны 11 / 12, доступные из Windows SDK, а в OpenGL зоопарк начная со второй версии до 4.6, плюс прорва разных расширений на разных платформах. А еще есть урезанные OpenGl ES

Comment: Для кросс-платформенности есть всякие Dxvk и Vkd3d, которые эмулируют directx поверх других API.

Comment: Да и сейчас много новых модных API появилось. Vulkan, webgpu...